# Error: "[ Error writing /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: No such file or directory ]" while trying to edit "httpd.conf" file and save it back

Tags: macos, apache, tomcat, clickjacking

To avoid click jacking attack for web applications hosted on my locally hosted apache-tomcat web server, I'm trying to edit "httpd.conf" file to append X-options to it.

Open file with "sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"
Appending the file with "Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN""
Control X
Given Y, when it asks me whether to save or not
Pressed "return" for confirming the location specified.

Gives me an error "[ Error writing /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: No such file or directory ]"

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. 
You may find help on another forum. Computer enthusiasts and power users, ask on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

does /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf exist?

if yes please check the permission of it (after change ) that have httpd user permission (owner and permissions)